# VB .net server and client

Tags: vb.net, sockets, client-server

I'm using `vb.net` server and client application. I'm using `system.net.sockets`.

Can I use `java`, `c++` or `php` in server side? If so, please, tell me how. If not please guide me on how to speed up my application.

Comment: The information you provided is not sufficient to answer your question. Pleas be more specific: what version of web-server are you using, if any (I assume it's IIS, but which one 6.0 or 7.0)? What's your application: a website or client-server application? The more info you give the more precise answer will be.

Comment: Yes. But SO is not the place to receive a tutorial in socket programming in one language, let alone 3. OTOH, you haven't provided anywhere near enough information for us to assess *whether* switching to another language would allow a significant speed up.

Comment: @Damien_ Why not? (Honest question. It certainly took me a while to learn my way to the Java tutorials and a little help pointing me to them was appreciated when it occurred way back when.)

Comment: @Phil - I guess I phrased it poorly, You might get links to tutorials, but you wouldn't expect someone to include an actual tutorial in an SO answer. And searching for "Java sockets tutorial" led me almost directly to the link you've posted.

Comment: @Damien_ My bad...I see you wrote "receive a tutorial" not "receive a tutorial link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Java Tutorial info about sockets:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Other networking stuff on Java is nearby. Java can run on Apache Tomcat server as well as several others.

Hard to recommend ways to speed up your setup without more details. 
In my experience, there's often more to be gained from "doing it right" (if there are inefficiencies in a setup) than there are from switching systems.

Comment: Those were very helpful for me now i want to create same client which connect through sockets using flex can you please guide me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have personal experience with that tech. Maybe someone else? Good luck!